# Runtime error 5: Invalid procedure call or arguement

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA coding and have just started working on them. I tried writing a code to count the number of selected items in a slicer, but while compiling I got the following error:

> Runtime error 5 - invalid procedure call or argument.

I have highlighted the line in which I am getting the error. Can someone please help me with the error?

[image]

I have tried using similar declarations for myslicer variable in other workbooks for different purposes and it works in those files.

Comment: What Excel version are you on? And does "Slicer_mode" actually exist? Add a debug watch to `ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches` and check its contents.

Comment: Please embed the code into the question. You spent more effort taking that screenshot and uploading it here than it would have been to copy+paste the actual code into the post.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the ActiveWorkbook is the correct one.

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

Comment: Thanks I tried adding above line to the code to activate the workbook, but the error is still there.

Comment: Ok. Then we need to make sure that the slicer name is wrote correctly. If it's ok check make this change `For Each slice In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches` instead the line that you wrote before.

Comment: Ok. I tried that as well, but the issue still persists... I am unable to understand the cause of the error... :/